# Python: panda dataframe split string in each row with occasional empty row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe with a column `attr`:

```
attr
valA

valA||valB||valC
vaB||valC
```

Note that the second row has no value. I want to create another column that contains the number of attributes in `attr`, so it would be like:

```
attr               num_attr
valA               1
                   0
valA||valB||valC   3
vaB||valC          2
```

I have tried:

```
df["num_attr"] = df["attr"].map(lambda a: len(a.split("||")))
```

But it says (due to the empty row, I presume):

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `|` is special regex character is necessary escape it by `\` in [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then get lengths by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), replace missing values and convert to integers:

```
df["num_attr"] = df["attr"].str.split("\|\|").str.len().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
               attr  num_attr
0              valA         1
1               NaN         0
2  valA||valB||valC         3
3         vaB||valC         2
```

Another similar solution with [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) and adding `1`:

```
df["num_attr"] = df["attr"].str.count("\|\|").add(1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

If want use your solution add `if-else` statement with [`pandas.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html):

```
df["num_attr"] = df["attr"].map(lambda a: len(a.split("||")) if pd.notna(a) else 0)
```

Or:

```
df["num_attr"] = df["attr"].map(lambda a: a.count("||") + 1 if pd.notna(a) else 0)
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I did not know about the `|` being a special character in `Series.str.split`